# Show result of js function call in django template

Tags: javascript

I have simple part of django template (simplified for readability) that executes js function to calculate the result (say, result is 100):

```
<script>
  function calculate() {
   //do calculation
   alert(result); //works fine: shows dialog box with "100".
   return result;
  }   
</script> 
<p>Result: <script>calculate()</script>.</p>
```

So i expect to see "Result:100." on the rendered page, but see only "Result:.". So the "calculate" function is executed and works fine (alert shows "100") but the result of its execution isn't displayed at the html page rendered from template.

Why? I guess I misunderstand some basics about page loading :(

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Python or Django, I've removed those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a value from a JS function doesn't insert it into the page. You would need to do that explicitly. One good way is to have an empty span with a specific ID, and insert the value into that span:

```
<p>Result: <span id="calcuation_result"></span>.</p>
<script>document.getElementById('calculation_result').innerText = calculate();</script>
```